# Error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api

Tags: apache-spark

For the life of me, I cannot seem to determine why I keep getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
```

My code reads from my Kafka Cluster using my api credentials. Is there any thoughts to what is causing this error and are there any solutions. I am working in Jupyter Notebook with Python.

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` with message `Could not initialize class ...` means that the JVM has already tried and failed to load the mentioned class. There may be a different exception the first time the JVM tries to load this class. The first step is to see if you can find this exception.

Comment: This error is common if you're using the incorrect package versions. For example, the Kafka library version for Spark Streaming needs to match your running Spark version. Please show your code

Comment: My Pyspark Version is 3.2.1. My Kafka Python version is 2.0.2 and my confluent Kafka is 1.8.2.